# Sound only comes through subwoofer

Tags: windows-7, audio

The sound on my windows 7 machine only comes through the subwoofer.  No sound comes through the speakers.

Any idea why? Or what I can do to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of things to check:

- Are your speakers plugged in properly?
- If it's a stereo speaker set, the subwoofer probably plugs into one of the speakers, or the speakers might plug into the subwoofer, depending on what kind you have (I've seen both).
- If you are using surround sound speakers, is the computer configured for surround output?
- If the speakers have an external amplifier, make sure that the speakers are properly connected to the amplifier, and the computer is connected to the computer properly.
- Try the speakers with another computer, or with another compatible device.

Answer (score 0):

here might be the solution to your problem... much luck :)

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-PC-Sound-and-Audio/IDT-driver-update-No-sound-from-the-built-in-speakers/td-p/384427/page/2

Comment: How? Can you please tell us the important steps here?